# Подключить свой список IP-адресов в fail2ban

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Сервер Ubuntu 16.04. Задача такая:

Есть список IP-адресов, для которых хочу установить "вечный бан" к моему серверу. И не важно запрашивается доступ к web, SSH или к чему-либо еще. Нужно создать файл со списком адресов и каким-то образом подключить его к конфигу fail2ban.

Список будет пополнятся. Так же необходимо перечислять не только конкретный IP, но и подсети, например 123.123.123.*

Это возможно сделать? как?

При изменении этого файла со списком нужно ли перезапускать fail2ban?

Comment: будет ли он одновременно работать с fail2ban? не будет ли каких-то конфликтов?

Comment: Лучше настроить на уровне `iptables`, сделать правила дропающие пакеты с заданных IP сетей. С `fail2ban` - конфликтов не будет. Но блокировать целые подсети плохая практика, можно случайно заблочить и потерять клиентов, делать всё нужно с умом.